# Org Numbered Lists Break with Src Block

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I want a numbered list of instructions where one or more steps show commands to be typed in.   I use BEGIN_SRC blocks and when exported to LaTeX the numbering has started over.  Even using [@4] doesn't work

```
* Instructions
To do the thing
1. Wax on
2. Wax off
3. From the cmd line
#+BEGIN_SRC bash
$> cd foo
$> bar --out results.txt
#+END_SRC
4. Lather
5. Rinse
6. Repeat
```

How can I have the list stay  continously numbered?

Comment: Have you tried indenting the src block so it's under item 3. ? In your question the block is not indented. I think this will fix problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Melioratus suggests, you need to indent item contents (including the source block) in order to keep the list in  place:

```
* Instructions
To do the thing
  1. Wax on
  2. Wax off
  3. From the cmd line
     #+BEGIN_SRC bash
     $> cd foo
     $> bar --out results.txt
     #+END_SRC
  4. Lather
  5. Rinse
  6. Repeat
```

Comment: Yes, the advice worked and I see how to do this now.